# Xelatex extended mode

Tags: xepersian

I want to compile a simple file as follows :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\begin{document}
سلام دنیا!
\end{document}
```

but I get an error. Here is the log file :

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.2) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.2.27)  20 DEC 2021 20:51
entering extended mode
**./untitled-1.tex
(untitled-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> xparse <2020-03-03>
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
```

I updated miketex and i think it solved the problem.Using texworks i getting output. But using texmaker i get the fallowing log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.12.20)  20 DEC 2021 21:28
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./untitled-1.tex
(untitled-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\xepersian.sty
Package: xepersian 2020/05/17 v23.1 Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.st
y
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xp
arse.sty
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-
xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-12-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count187
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count188
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count189
\g__graphics_track_int=\count190
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count192
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count193
))
Package: xparse 2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xe
tex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cf
g)))
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\xepersian-persi
ancal.sty
Package: xepersian-persiancal 2012/07/25 v0.2 provides Persian calendar
\XePersian@i=\count271
\XePersian@y=\count272
\XePersian@m=\count273
\XePersian@d=\count274
\XePersian@latini=\count275
\XePersian@persiani=\count276
\XePersian@latinii=\count277
\XePersian@persianii=\count278
\XePersian@latiniii=\count279
\XePersian@persianiii=\count280
\XePersian@latiniv=\count281
\XePersian@persianiv=\count282
\XePersian@latinv=\count283
\XePersian@persianv=\count284
\XePersian@latinvi=\count285
\XePersian@persianvi=\count286
\XePersian@latinvii=\count287
\XePersian@persianvii=\count288
\XePersian@latinviii=\count289
\XePersian@persianviii=\count290
\XePersian@latinix=\count291
\XePersian@persianix=\count292
\XePersian@latinx=\count293
\XePersian@persianx=\count294
\XePersian@latinxi=\count295
\XePersian@persianxi=\count296
\XePersian@latinxii=\count297
\XePersian@persianxii=\count298
\XePersian@persianxiii=\count299
\XePersian@temp=\count300
\XePersian@temptwo=\count301
\XePersian@tempthree=\count302
\XePersian@yModHundred=\count303
\XePersian@thirtytwo=\count304
\XePersian@dn=\count305
\XePersian@sn=\count306
\XePersian@mminusone=\count307
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\xepersian-maths
digitspec.sty
Package: xepersian-mathsdigitspec 2018/12/16 v1.1.7 Unicode Persian maths digit
s in XeLaTeX
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\bidi.sty
Package: bidi 2020/05/17 v36.3 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX


****************************************************
* 
* bidi package (Bidirectional typesetting in
* plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
* 
* Description: A convenient interface for
* typesetting bidirectional texts in plain TeX
* and LaTeX. The package includes adaptations
* for use with many other commonly-used packages.
* 
* Copyright (c) 2007--2020 Vafa Khalighi
* Copyright (c) 2018--2020 bidi-tex GitHub organization
* 
* v36.3, 2020/05/17
* 
* License: LaTeX Project Public License, version
* 1.3c or higher (your choice)
* 
* Location on CTAN: /macros/xetex/latex/bidi
* 
* Issue tracker: https://github.com/persiantex/bidi/issues
* 
* Primary author of bidi package: Vafa Khalighi.
* 
****************************************************
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\biditools.sty
Package: biditools 2020/05/13 v2 Programming tools for bidi package
\@bidi@envbody=\toks16
\@bidi@emptytoks=\toks17
\bidi@poscount=\count308

Package biditools Warning: Patching `\enddocument' failed on input line 916.

\bidi@tempcountb=\count309
\bidi@temptoksa=\toks18
\bidi@temptoksb=\toks19
\bidi@dummies=\count310
\bidi@are@these@correct=\toks20
\bidi@toks@lista=\toks21
\bidi@toks@listb=\toks22
\bidi@stack@length=\count311
\bidi@empty@stack=\toks23
\bidi@looprepeat@depth=\count312
) (C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/zref\zref-abspage.sty
Package: zref-abspage 2020-05-28 v2.31 Module abspage for zref (HO)

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/zref\zref-base.sty
Package: zref-base 2020-05-28 v2.31 Module base for zref (HO)

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys
.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexc
mds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
Package zref Info: New property list: main on input line 763.
Package zref Info: New property: default on input line 764.
Package zref Info: New property: page on input line 765.
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.st
y
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\c@abspage=\count313
Package zref Info: New property: abspage on input line 66.
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.te
x
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.t
ex
\XKV@toks=\toks24
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks25

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex
))
\XKV@depth=\count314
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\@bidi@copyins@=\insert252

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\latex-xetex-b
idi.def
File: latex-xetex-bidi.def 2019/03/03 v1.3.7 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' f
or XeTeX engine
\bidi@n@everypar=\toks26
\bidi@column@check@number=\count315

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\footnote-xete
x-bidi.def
File: footnote-xetex-bidi.def 2017/08/09 v1.1 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX en
gine
\c@footdir@label=\count316
\footdir@toks=\toks27
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\article-xetex
-bidi.def
File: article-xetex-bidi.def 2017/06/09 v0.6 bidi adaptations for standard arti
cle class for XeTeX engine
))
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/bidi\loadingorder-
xetex-bidi.def
File: loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def 2017/12/29 v0.97 making sure that bidi is the
 last package loaded
)
\bidi@digits=\count317
\bidi@digits@charclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
\bidi@sepmark@charclass=\XeTeXcharclass2
)
****************************************************
* 
* xepersian package (Persian for LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
* 
* Description: The package supports Persian
* typesetting, using fonts provided in the
* distribution.
* 
* Copyright (c) 2008--2020 Vafa Khalighi
* Copyright (c) 2018--2020 bidi-tex GitHub Organization
* 
* v23.1, 2020/05/17
* 
* License: LaTeX Project Public License, version
* 1.3c or higher (your choice)
* 
* Location on CTAN: /macros/xetex/latex/xepersian
* 
* Issue tracker: https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues
* 
* Primary author of xepersian package: Vafa Khalighi.
* 
****************************************************
\xepersian@tcl=\count318
\xepersian@ilg=\dimen142
\xepersian@strutilg=\dimen143

(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\loadingorder-xe
persian.def
File: loadingorder-xepersian.def 2018/09/29 v0.5 making sure that xepersian is 
the last package loaded
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\footnote-xepers
ian.def
File: footnote-xepersian.def 2017/08/09 v0.6 footnote macros for xepersian pack
age
)
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xepersian\article-xepersi
an.def
File: article-xepersian.def 2010/07/25 v0.2 adaptations for standard article cl
ass
)

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'lmroman10-regular(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'lmroman10-regular' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Path,BoldFont={lmroman10-bold},BoldItalic
Font={lmroman10-bolditalic},ItalicFont={lmroman10-italic},SmallCapsFont={lmroma
ncaps10-regular},SlantedFont={lmromanslant10-regular},BoldSlantedFont={lmromans
lant10-bold}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmroman10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;map
ping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmroman10-bold]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mappin
g=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmroman10-italic]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapp
ing=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'slanted' (m/sl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromanslant10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dfl
t;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'slanted small caps'  (m/scsl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmroman10-bolditalic]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;
mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold slanted' (b/sl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromanslant10-bold]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;m
apping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold slanted small caps'  (b/scsl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[lmromancaps10-regular]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt
;mapping=tex-text;"

)

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Yas/BI" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Yas/B" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Yas/I" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Yas(0)' created for font 'Yas' with
(fontspec)             options [Script=Persian,Ligatures=PersianTeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Yas/OT:script=arab;language=dflt;mapping=persian-tex
-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 


No file untitled-1.aux.
\openout1 = `untitled-1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 6
.
(C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

[1

] (untitled-1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5532 strings out of 411044
 148455 string characters out of 2824780
 576187 words of memory out of 3000000
 26135 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403558 words of font info for 43 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 88i,5n,97p,1040b,252s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on untitled-1.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the full log, please provide the full log.

Comment: it is all the content of .log file .

Comment: Then where's the error? There is no error is that listing

Comment: For fun, since it is miktex, have you updated miktex?

Comment: Does that font exist in your font system folder?

Comment: Don't kill the compilation if you get an error. Type `x` and hit enter, then xelatex can finish the log.

Comment: for now i am trying to update miketex, maybe it solves the problem.

Comment: I am almost sure it is not font problem cause it was working before.

Comment: where should i type the 'x' ?

Comment: @daleif
i guess updating was the solution but still there are some problem. i do not know maybe is non relevant to this question.

Comment: You still eed to describe the problem. As far as I can see from the log, there is no error listed in the log

Comment: Not at pc, so cannot test the code

Comment: Well, there isn't anything wrong with your code or your log. What does your output look like? As long as you have an updated distribution AND the font installed in your system (which seems to be the case), this should work. How does the output look like? Any problem with that? Clearly there is an output: `Output written on untitled-1.pdf (1 page).`